# SwipeView and FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragmentpageradapter, swipeview

Right now i'm trying to program an android-application with a navigation drawer and swipe views. When selecting "Timetable" in the navigation drawer, the app opens a swipe view with 6 pages with the page number on every page.
The problem is that - when re-selecting the page "Timetable" in the navigation drawer - the pages 5 and 6 are displayed but the content (fragment) won't load.

I used the code of the swipe view-example:  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

This should be the fragment with the swipe views:

```
public class Timetable extends Fragment {
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    public TimeTable() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_stundenplantag,
                container, false);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this.getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Here's the class SectionsPagerAdapter:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 6 total pages.
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
            case 5:
                return getString(R.string.title_section6).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And last but not least here's the DummySectionFragment-class:

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                    container, false);

            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.append("Page "
                    + Integer.toString(getArguments()
                            .getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),String.valueOf(getArguments().get(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```